# Is there a way to avoid Swift retain/release for high performance code?

Tags: swift, performance, caching

I wanted to write a Swift version of the classic cache data structure that uses a array up until a certain configurable limit, then switches to a map[2].
Unfortunately the performance characteristics I get when writing even simpler data structure makes me think that this is not doable in swift at the moment.

Consider this piece of code :

```
import Foundation

let aKey = 196
var cache: [(Int, String)] = []

for _ in 0..<1_000_000_000
{
    var t: String?
    for (k, v) in cache
    {
        if k == aKey
        {
            t = v
            break
        }
    }

    if t == nil
    {
        let str = "some cache value with key=\(aKey)"
        cache.append((aKey, str))
        t = str
    }
}
```

This takes around 0.785s to execute.

This other program, which should be roughly equivalent :

```
import Foundation

struct DummyCache<K:Hashable, V>
{
    var array:[(K, V?)] = []

    subscript(index: K) -> V?
    {
        get
        {
            for (k, v) in array
            {
                if k == index
                {
                    return v
                }
            }

            return nil
        }
        set(newValue)
        {
            array.append((index, newValue))
        }
    }
}

let aKey = 196
var cache: DummyCache<Int, String> = DummyCache()
cache[aKey] = "some cache value with key=\(aKey)"

for _ in 0..<1_000_000_000
{
    var t: String? = cache[aKey]
}
```

Is in fact 45x slower! (around 35.532s)

When profiling this code, I can see that most of the time is spent in the swift runtime : 
[image: profile]

**Is there a way to improve the performance of this ?**

---

[2] For the record, here is the data structure I had in mind :

```
import Foundation

struct Cache<K:Hashable, V>
{
    let limit: Int
    var array:[(K, V)]? = nil
    var map: [K:V]? = nil
    let buildValueFromKey: (K) -> V

    init(limit: Int = 20, buildValueFromKey:@escaping (K) -> V) //optimal limit depends, must conduct tests to find optimal value
    {
        self.limit = limit
        self.buildValueFromKey = buildValueFromKey
    }

    subscript(index: K) -> V
    {
        mutating get
        {
            if var map = map
            {
                if let res = map[index]
                {
                    return res
                }
                else
                {
                    let res = buildValueFromKey(index)
                    map[index] = res
                    return res
                }
            }
            else //array mode
            {
                if array == nil
                {
                    let res = buildValueFromKey(index)
                    array = [(index, res)]
                    return res
                }
                //else

                for (k, v) in array! //can't be null at that point
                {
                    if k == index
                    {
                        return v
                    }
                }

                // array does not contain index at this point, create & append it
                let res = buildValueFromKey(index)
                array!.append((index, res))
                return res
            }
        }
    }
}

let aKey = 196
var cache: Cache<Int, String> = Cache{ "some cache value with key=\($0)" }

for _ in 0..<1_000_000_000
{
    var t: String? = cache[aKey]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So good question and still no answer. I haven't profiled your code, but have some possible solution. In case you experience performance drops with array of objects (not of structs/POTs), take a looks at `ContiguousArray` - it was invented especially to eliminate retains/releases moving to block-based allocations.

Here is official docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/contiguousarray
And more tips for inspiration: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/OptimizationTips.rst